# Convert java SQL query to R programming SQL query

Tags: java, mysql, sql, r

I have a java `SQL` query and I want to convert it into `R` programming `SQL` query using `RMySQL package`.

This my java SQL query:

```
 String Statement1 = "((Time_To_Sec((case when shift_to >= shift_from then TIMEDIFF(shift_to,shift_from) else TIMEDIFF('24:00:00',TIMEDIFF(shift_from,shift_to)) end))-" +
                "               (case when lunch_from is not null then TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(lunch_to,lunch_from)) else 0 end)-" +
                "               (case when break1_from is not null then TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(break1_to,break1_from)) else 0 end)- " +
                "               (case when break2_from is not null then TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(break2_to,break2_from))else 0 end))/3600)";
```

How do I convert this java `SQL` supported query to `R` programming supported query. I am using `RMySQL package`. I am doing like this but its not working:

```
Statement1 = dbGetQuery(mydb , "((Time_To_Sec((case when shift_to >= shift_from then TIMEDIFF(shift_to,shift_from) else TIMEDIFF('24:00:00',TIMEDIFF(shift_from,shift_to)) end))-" +
  "             (case when lunch_from is not null then TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(lunch_to,lunch_from)) else 0 end)-" +
  "             (case when break1_from is not null then TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(break1_to,break1_from)) else 0 end)- " +
  "             (case when break2_from is not null then TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(break2_to,break2_from))else 0 end))/3600)")
```

Thanks

Comment: Write your sql query as you would do normally as one line.

Comment: or wrap your strings in `paste` and replace `+` with `,`.

Comment: That is not a compliant SQL query -no `SELECT` or `FROM` clause. Is your Java statement cut off?

Comment: Using paste and replacing + with , also not working. Giving some SQL syntax error.